# why is print(eval(repr(instance))) calling the str function and not repr function?

Tags: python, string, repr

in the below code block why is the statement print(new) calling str function and not calling repr function. is it because the print function was called?

```
class Robot:

    def __init__(self, name, build_year):
        self.name = name
        self.build_year = build_year

    def __repr__(self):
    return "Robot('" + self.name + "', " + str(self.build_year) + ")"

    def __str__(self):
    return "Name: " + self.name + ", Build Year: " + str(self.build_year)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = Robot("Marvin", 1979)


print(str(x))
print(x)
print(repr(x))
new = eval(repr(x))
print(new)


answer is 
Name: Marvin, Build Year: 1979
Name: Marvin, Build Year: 1979
Robot('Marvin', 1979)
Name: Marvin, Build Year: 1979
```

Comment: Do you know what ``eval`` does?

Comment: Because that is what the `print` function will try to use

Comment: Because `new=eval(repr(x))` is equivalent to `new=Robot('Marvin', 1979)`, i.e. it generates a new object, whose str() function gets called afterwards.

Comment: @tif thanks tif .that is a perfect answer !!

Comment: @Mike Scotty . yes

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs for print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and
> written to the stream <...>

So yes, `print` calls `__str__` of the object.